# Building a Binary Kernel Module Package (Kmod)

Tags: kernel-module, rpmbuild

**TL;DR** What is the *correct* way to include the minor version in the `%dist` tag when building for different Kernel ABI releases?

I am using several "kmod" packages from CentOS as examples because the [documentation](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/BuildingKernelModules#head-b86b6eec08d5719cf1838929f26a64af88e2b7f0) appears to be somewhat outdated. One of which is found here; [oracleasm-2.0.8-13.el6_8.src.rpm](http://vault.centos.org/6.8/updates/Source/SPackages/oracleasm-2.0.8-13.el6_8.src.rpm)

There is nothing in the spec file to set the `%dist` tag to `el6_8`, so I can assume it is passed on the command line.

```
rpmbuild -bb --define 'dist .el6_7' oracleasm.spec
```

**Edit:** The [build log](http://buildlogs.centos.org/c7.1511.00/oracleasm/20151122174721/2.0.8-15.el7.centos.x86_64/build.log) contradicts that this is the answer. So, maybe %dist is set in their environment.

> ENTER do(['bash', '--login', '-c', 'rpmbuild -bb --target x86_64 --nodeps  builddir/build/SPECS/oracleasm.spec'],

**Additionally:**
Is this the Red Hat way of doing it? Can (should) an el6_7 and el6_8 package exist in the same custom/internal repository? Will an upgrade from a 6.7 Kernel package to a 6.8 Kernel gracefully update the module (given availability in the repository?) Or, should I segregate packages based on %dist and reconfigure Yum to point to a different baseurl when updating the Kernel from one minor release to the next?

I am working on testing the section above, but I am also asking these questions here to leverage the knowlege of the community and to discuss what might be best practice - which is often different than if something just works.

Comment: `%dist` is set by one of the default system macros on RHEL6 and beyond. It didn't exist previously, so you will sometimes see `%{?dist}` meaning to use it if available but not error out if not. If you are repackaging from scratch, it is best to override it.

Comment: Also, `%dist` is only used to show which distro it came from. I believe `yum` will just pull the largest number.

Comment: Sorry, I might not have been as clear as I could have. [Here](http://vault.centos.org/6.7/updates/x86_64/Packages/kmod-bnx2x-firmware-1.712.30_0-1.el6_7.x86_64.rpm) and in other examples it seems to be used with the OS minor version included as well. (When kABI incompatibilities occur.)